# "Open in Low Resolution" from command line

Tags: macos, retina, hidpi

Mac OS provides the handy functionality of rendering an application in in low non-retina resolution by setting a checkbox "Open in Low Resolution" in the application info. However, for development, I start my application using a run configuration from my IDE.

How can I start the application in low resolution with a command I can put into the run configurations, or from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-AppleMagnifiedMode YES` to your command line, or to “Arguments Passed On Launch” in your scheme.

[image: scheme screen shot]

This works for most apps, which put command-line arguments into the `NSUserDefaults` “registration domain” and otherwise ignore them.

However, some apps, in particular those that were originally Linux apps and that use cross-platform toolkits, do not ignore their command-line arguments. For example, [Inkscape](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/9e3a25b6f5f15627ea2124ec13319ddf0766487a/src/inkscape-main.cpp#L256) uses the [Gnome GIO toolkit](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/) to parse the command line arguments. Since it doesn't explicitly tell GIO about the `AppleMagnifiedMode` option, GIO rejects it. There is no particularly good workaround for such an app.