# macOS „Open in Low Resolution” from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, resolution, mode

I’d like to open an app from the terminal using the “Open in low resolution” mode, which normally can be achieved by triggering an appropriate checkbox in file info. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Open in Low Resolution" from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382237/open-in-low-resolution-from-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

pass the argument `-AppleMagnifiedMode YES`

most applications (not all) recognize it

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me what exact command should I write? If I open a program from terminal by typing its name stated in binaries located in /usr/local/bin/, how can I include -AppleMagnifiedMode YES?
Typing just `<program_name> -AppleMagnifiedMode YES` doesn't work

Comment: the argument should work with common GUI Applications, ex. `/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview -AppleMagnifiedMode YES`

Comment: Ok, so if I have created a symlink for a binary in /Applications/..., which is located in /usr/local/bin I cannot run it in Low Resolution this way?

Comment: yes, you can. Pass the parameter when launching the application using the symlink

Answer (score 0):

In response to passing `-AppleMagnifiedMode YES`,

[Screenshot from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoLsu.png)

It doesn't seem to work.